# C++ 'stod()' not working, and 'strtod()' is throwing an error during compilation

Tags: c++

So I am still new to C++ and I wanted to see if I could print a result based on user input using the code below.

The Code:

```
/* Input Example */
// Initialization
// Euler's Constant
double eulersConstant = rand();

// Euler's Guess
string eulersGuess;
// Euler's Guess (Double)
double eulersGuessDouble;

// Print
cout << "What is Euler's Constant?";

// Input
getline(cin, eulersGuess);

// Update > Euler's Guess (Double)
eulersGuessDouble = strtod(eulersGuess);

/* Logic
   If
   Euler's Guess (Double) is Euler's Constant.
   > Print
*/
if (eulersGuessDouble == eulersConstant)
   cout << "\tYour guess was right! -- 'Outstanding'" << endl;

else
   cout << "\tYour guess was wrong! -- 'One in a million chance there...'" << endl;
```

When I compile this using `g++` from Windows command prompt, I get this error:

> ```
> Learning C.cpp:116:47: error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'double strtod(const char*, char**)'
>      eulersGuessDouble = strtod(eulersGuess);
>                                            ^
> ```

And of course, all this code is within the `int main()` function.
I think the problem might be originating from the `strtod()` function but any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) accepts C-like strings aka char array

```
double strtod(const char *str, char **endptr);
```

so you **cant** pass instance of class [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), but you may get pointer to constant chararacter array which this object contains using [`c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method.

```
eulersGuess.c_str();
```

Or you may use function [`std::stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) which accepts `std::string` parameters.

**[[Live on ideone]](https://ideone.com/8bmaab)**